# Fixing TFS Branches (Visual Studio solution is on the root of the team project)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

I was about to branch some code when I realized that our visual studio solution is actually on the root of the team project.

```
$
  -> 
     Proj1
       -> 
         Solution files
```

Instead of:

```
$
  -> 
     Proj1
       -> 
         Trunk
             -> 
                Solution files
```

I was thinking about creating a Trunk folder under the team project Proj1 and moving all the existing solution files there. And then, I creating another folder under Proj1 called Branches and start branching the code there.

Please suggest a good solution as we have several developers working on the code. Thank you.

**Edit**

This is a pretty good article on TFS source control structure: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668992.aspx I am not sure what impact it is going to have on the current development if I create new folders and move the files around.

Comment: This is a pretty good article on TFS source control structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668992.aspx
I am not sure what impact it is going to have on the current development if I create new folders and move the files around.

Comment: Before creating your branches, read http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking is along the right lines.  A good practice is to always have a layer in your folder structure that represents the branch (even if you're not currently doing more than one branch).  I'll usually structure my initial folders like this:

```
$\Project Foo\MAIN\Foo.sln
```